# Using Insert_batch but in the mysql looping null

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, insert, batch-insert

I'm using an insert batch for insert more than 1 data (array), it works but in MySQL showing the data is looping a lot of null data

have tried to use regular insert but doesn't work because the data is an array

Controller

```php
public function importpenelitian(){
        // Load plugin PHPExcel nya
        include APPPATH.'third_party/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';

        $excelreader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
        $loadexcel = $excelreader->load('excel/'.$this->filename.'.xlsx'); // Load file yang telah diupload ke folder excel
        $sheet = $loadexcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true ,true);

        // Buat sebuah variabel array untuk menampung array data yg akan kita insert ke database
        $data = array();

        $numrow = 1;
        foreach($sheet as $row){
            // Cek $numrow apakah lebih dari 1
            // Artinya karena baris pertama adalah nama-nama kolom
            // Jadi dilewat saja, tidak usah diimport
            if($numrow > 1){
                // Kita push (add) array data ke variabel data
                array_push($data, array(
                    'Inisial'=>$row['B'], // Insert data Insiial dari kolom B di excel
                    'Jurusan'=>$row['C'], // Insert data Jurusan dari kolom B di excel
                    'Prodi'=>$row['D'], // Insert data Prodi dari kolom C di excel
                    'Jenis_Hibah'=>$row['E'], // Insert data Jenis Hibah dari kolom E di excel
                    'Tahun'=>$row['F'], // Insert data Tahun dari kolom F di excel
                    'Judul'=>$row['G'], // Insert data Judul dari kolom G di excel
                    'Anggaran'=>$row['H'], // Insert data Anggaran dari kolom H di excel
                    'Status'=>$row['I'], // Insert data Status dari kolom I di excel
                    'Laporan'=>$row['J'], // Insert data Jenis Hibah dari kolom E di excel
                    'Status_Pengusul'=>$row['K'], // Insert data Status pengusul dari kolom E di excel
                    'Verifikasi'=>$row['L'], // Insert data verifikasih dari kolom E di excel
                ));
            }

            $numrow++; // Tambah 1 setiap kali looping
        }

        // Panggil fungsi insert_multiple yg telah kita buat sebelumnya di model
        $this->m_import->insert_multiple($data);

        redirect("Admin/form_penelitian"); // Redirect ke halaman awal (ke controller IMPORT fungsi index)
    }
```

Model

```php
public function insert_multiple($data){
        $this->db->insert('dt_penelitian',$data);
        //$this->db->insert_batch('dt_penelitian', $data);
    }
```

want to insert a data (array) in MySQL without having another looping null data

Comment: so the inserted data is different from the `$data` data? could you do `var_export($data)` (before the `insert_multiple()`) to see what's inside that array?

Comment: how can i see the array?? can you explain that??

Comment: do you want to avoid insert `null` rows which are existed in your `excel` file ?

Comment: @SilviaNovita if you write `var_export($data);die();` before `$this->m_import->insert_multiple($data);`, it will show you the data inside the `$data`.

Comment: yes i want to avoid insert null row

Comment: the data is show

Comment: @SilviaNovita could you paste the data here?

Comment: array ( 0 => array ( 'Inisial' => 'DDS', 'Jurusan' => 'Jurusan Teknologi Informasi', 'Prodi' => 'SI', 'Jenis_Hibah' => 'Hibah Kerjasama', 'Tahun' => 2018, 'Judul' => 'Gurindam Workforce Development Program (GUR-WDP)', 'Anggaran' => 3821050000, 'Status' => 'Diterima', 'Laporan' => 'Belum', 'Status_Pengusul' => 'Anggota', 'Verifikasi' => 'Sudah', ), )